# Prove that each non-negative integer up to $5^{k}-1$ can be expressed in base 5 using at most k digits.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that each non-negative integer up to $5^{k}-1$ can be expressed in base 5 using at most $k$ digits.

Clearly it is true for $k=0$, in which case we simply express $5^{0}-1$ as $0$ in base k.  I proceed with strong induction.  Now assume we can express all non-negative integers up to $5^{k}-1$ in base 5 using at most k digits. Now clearly when I add another digit, I can now get as high as $5^{k+1}-1$.  But I am wondering how to formally prove I can also cover all the numbers n where  $(5^{k}-1) < n < (5^{k+1}-1)$.

I chose base 5 arbitrarily.    One could also have chosen base 10.

Comment: A non-negative integer $n$ with at most $k$ digits in base $b$ can be written as $n=\overline{a_{k-1}a_{k-2}\dots a_1a_0}_{\,(b)}$ $=a_{k-1}b^{k-1}+a_{k-2}b^{k-2}+\dots+a_1b+a_0$ where $0 \le a_j \lt b$. Think at what the minimum and maximum values of $n$ can be.

Comment: Thanks, so this is akin to the Basis Representation Theorem.  I did just go through the proof and it made sense.  The line of reasoning of the proof was that for each representation of n to the base k, there is a representation of n-1.

Comment: You should clarify what definition for "*expressed in base 5*" you use, and what properties of the representation you know (existence, uniqueness etc).